# Homework for lecture # 5

Tags: marlowe-pioneer-program

How do I review the homework for lecture 5?  There is no folder 'lecture05' in https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-pioneer-program/tree/main/code/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-pioneer-program/tree/lecture05/code/src/lecture05/homework) is the homework for Lecture 5.